# Not able to make HTTP callout to salesforce service from Batch class?

Tags: batch, singleemailmessage

Not able to make HTTP callout to salesforce rest service from Batch class. In rest service we have a code to send emails. Earlier it was working fine but since last few days emails are not being sent when batch job runs. But when I hit the service through workbench it is working fine.

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated/

Comment: Can you please share your code here?

Comment: Hopefully your code is checking available limits vs limits consumed before making the callouts. Please post it for further help.